# how to make this flowchart

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, flow-charts

[image: i want to have this diagram . Your help would be really appreciated.:]

so i came to this code right now i m still stuck with the text in between arrows and that dashed box with correct and wrong emoji

so far I have this code :

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows.meta,
    backgrounds,
    fit,
    matrix,
    positioning,
    quotes}
    
    \tikzset{mytext/.style={font=\fontfamily{put}\selectfont\tiny,align=center,color=black}
        ,
    rec/.style={mytext,rectangle,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1.5cm,fill=Green,draw=red!150},}
    
    
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [rec] (a) {Initial broad high \\throughput \\screening};
    \coordinate [right = 2cm of a](b){};
    \coordinate [below = 2cm of b](c){};
    \node[rec,right=2cm  of c](d){Mixed variable\\ Multi-Objective\\ optimization};
    \coordinate [right = 2cm of d](e){};
    \coordinate [above = 2cm of e](f){};
    \node[rec,right=2cm of f](g){Scale-Up};
    \coordinate[above=2cm of f](k){};
    \node[rec,left=0.5cm of k](l){Further Continuous \\parameter optimization\\ for selected discrete \\ variable};
    \node[rec,left=1.2cm of l](m){xd};
    \draw[arrow,black] (a. east) -> (b. west);
    \draw[arrow,black] (b.east ) |- (d. west);
    \draw[arrow,black] (d.west) |- (e.mid east );
    \draw[arrow,black] (e. right) |- (f. left);
    \draw[arrow,black] (f. right) |- (g. left);
    \draw[arrow,black] (f. right) |- (k. left);
    \draw[arrow,black] (k. right) |- (l. right);
    \draw[arrow,black] (l. right) |- (m. right);
    \draw[arrow,black] (b. right) |- (m. left);
    
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE is missing `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` and the last `\node` should end with a semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using absolute coordinates, which gives, in my view, a little more control, at least in the beginning.

From a graphical design point of view I won't confuse your block diagram with remarks: Those are better suited for a concise comparison, and the tool for this is ... a table. And the way it is now, legibility is certainly an issue.

So let's focus on the diagram and look at some pecularities.

#### Beginning

Forget about the styles for a moment: you'll introduce them as needed while you go. Start with placing 5 nodes, your blocks.

```
    % ~~~ place your functional blocks ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[block] (A) at ( -4, 0) {Initial broad high \\throughput \\screening};
    \node[block] (M) at ( 4, 2){xd};
    \node[block] (L) at (10, 2){Further Continuous \\parameter optimization\\                                                   for selected discrete \\ variable};
    \node[block] (D) at ( 8,-2) {Mixed variable\\ Multi-Objective\\ optimization};  
    \node[block] (G) at (18, 0) {Scale-Up};
```

Their coordinates may be preliminary and you adjust them as you go (= compile often). Make sure, it's more or less what you wanted.

#### Connecting

First approach should always be to connect these nodes crisscross directly. Don't care about alignments etc. for a start.

While doing so it turned out to be useful to put 2 extra points after the input and before the output to simplify both arrow types and colors:

```
    % ~~~ some coordinates ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \coordinate (P1) at (2,0);
    \coordinate (P2) at (12,0);
```

#### Improving connections

Basically you start with introducing things like:

```
    % upper branch
    \draw[arr1] (P1) |- (M);
    \draw[arr1] (M)  -- (L);
...
```

Now it may turn out that it's useful to put some text nodes. Once you understood the path-idea from Tikz it's easier:

- path starts with `\`
- ends with `;`
- and everything in between is "action" (like in the movies)
- usually you just `draw`, but you can also put `node`s // watch the missing `\` here:

```
    \draw[arr1] (M)  -- node[txt]{Finalise\\discrete\\variable\\selection}
                        (L);
```

By default this is just put `midway`  (or at `pos=0.5`) between the two points, here (M) and (L). And here's just a variant for the upper feedback loop using some intermediate points in relative coordinates:

```
    \draw[arr1,dashed] (M.east) -- ++(0.5,0) -- ++(0,2)
                   -| node[txt,pos=.1]{Further\\reduction} (M.north);
```

Same idea, a bit more action before the path ends and Tikz tries rendering it; by using `pos=.1` or so you can move the text along the path, i.e. between its (shorter) start and end points.

#### Styles / Formats

They develop as you go. Besides moving them to the tikzpicture and using your definitions, you also see, how I tried using a hierarchial (=re-using prior definitions) approach for the arrows and lines.

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[% ~~~ move styles here ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    >={Stealth},    % replacing all arrow tips
    mytext/.style ={font=\fontfamily{put}\selectfont\tiny,
                    align=center,color=black},
    block/.style  ={mytext,rectangle,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1.5cm,
                    fill=green,draw=red!150},
    % ~~~ for all those lines (used hierarchically) ~~~~~~~~~
    lnw/.style={line width=2pt},
    arr/.style={->,lnw},
    arr1/.style={arr,draw=green!50!blue!100},
    arr2/.style={lnw,draw=green!50!blue!100},
    arr3/.style={arr,draw=teal!70!black!60},
    arr4/.style={lnw,draw=teal!70!black!60},
    % ~~~ for the text nodes ~~~~~~~~~~~
    txt/.style={fill=gray!10,align=center},% or just fill white
 ]
```

#### Final suggestion

For learning purposes I suggest doing the following:

- copy my code below into a new file
- delete everything (or comment it out) after the nodes
- compile
- repeat while deleting less code, i.e. "walking" through the connectors etc.

This way it's more evident, what's going on, and you can better grasp the meaning of each line of code.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone} % more useful during development

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

    
\begin{document}  
 \begin{tikzpicture}[% ~~~ move styles here ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    >={Stealth},    % replacing all arrow tips
    mytext/.style ={font=\fontfamily{put}\selectfont\tiny,
                    align=center,color=black},
    block/.style  ={mytext,rectangle,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1.5cm,
                    fill=green,draw=red!150},
    % ~~~ for all those lines (used hierarchically) ~~~~~~~~~
    lnw/.style={line width=2pt},
    arr/.style={->,lnw},
    arr1/.style={arr,draw=green!50!blue!100},
    arr2/.style={lnw,draw=green!50!blue!100},
    arr3/.style={arr,draw=teal!70!black!60},
    arr4/.style={lnw,draw=teal!70!black!60},
    % ~~~ for the text nodes ~~~~~~~~~~~
    txt/.style={fill=gray!10,align=center},
 ]
    % ~~~ place your functional blocks ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[block] (A) at ( -4, 0) {Initial broad high \\throughput \\screening};
    \node[block] (M) at ( 4, 2){xd};
    \node[block] (L) at (10, 2){Further Continuous \\parameter optimization\\                                                   for selected discrete \\ variable};
    \node[block] (D) at ( 8,-2) {Mixed variable\\ Multi-Objective\\ optimization};  
    \node[block] (G) at (18, 0) {Scale-Up}; 
    
    % ~~~ some coordinates ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \coordinate (P1) at (2,0);
    \coordinate (P2) at (12,0);
    
    % ~~~ connector paths with text-nodes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % input
    \draw[lnw]  (A)  -- node[txt]{Select best performing\\discrete variables}
                        (P1);
    
    % upper branch
    \draw[arr1] (P1) |- (M);
    \draw[arr1] (M)  -- node[txt]{Finalise\\discrete\\variable\\selection}
                        (L);
    \draw[arr2] (L)  -| (P2);
    
    \draw[arr1,dashed] (M.east) -- ++(0.5,0) -- ++(0,2)
                   -| node[txt,pos=.1]{Further\\reduction} (M.north); 
    
    % output
    \draw[arr]  (P2) -- node[txt]{Optimum continuous\\and\\discrete conditions}
                        (G);
    
    % lower branch
    \draw[arr3] (P1) |- (D);
    \draw[arr4] (D)  -| (P2);
 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

No solution yet, just some debugging to give you some feedback:

- looks like you puzzle `\node` and `\coordinate`
- `\node`s have a shape, hence dimension, hence `east`, `west` etc. are different points (or coordinates)
- `\coordinate`s have zero dimension, hence `east` etc. has no meaning

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone} % more useful during development

% ~~~ commented out all packages not needed here ~~~~~~~~
%    \usepackage{fourier}
%    \usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
%shapes,shadows,
arrows.meta,
%    backgrounds,
%    fit,
%    matrix,
    positioning,
%    quotes
}
%    
\tikzset{
    mytext/.style={font=\fontfamily{put}\selectfont\tiny,align=center,color=black},
    rec/.style={mytext,rectangle,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1.5cm,fill=green,draw=red!150},% <<< green
    arrow/.style={-{Stealth}},
}
    
    
\begin{document}  
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node       [rec]               (a) {Initial broad high \\throughput \\screening};
    \coordinate [right = 2cm of a]  (b);    %{}; !!! it's a coordinate, not a node
    \coordinate [below = 2cm of b]  (c);    %{};
    
    \node       [rec,right=2cm  of c](d){Mixed variable\\ Multi-Objective\\ optimization};
    \coordinate [right = 2cm of d]  (e);    %{};
    \coordinate [above = 2cm of e]  (f);    %{};
    
    \node       [rec,right=2cm of f](g){Scale-Up};
    \coordinate [above=2cm of f]    (k);    %{};
    
    \node       [rec,left=0.5cm of k](l){Further Continuous \\parameter optimization\\ 
                                         for selected discrete \\ variable};
    \node       [rec,left=1.2cm of l](m){xd};
    \draw[arrow,black] (a) -- (b);
%   \draw[arrow,black] (b.east ) |- (d.west);
%    \draw[arrow,black] (d.west) |- (e.mid east );
%    \draw[arrow,black] (e. right) |- (f. left);
%    \draw[arrow,black] (f. right) |- (g. left);
%    \draw[arrow,black] (f. right) |- (k. left);
%    \draw[arrow,black] (k. right) |- (l. right);
%    \draw[arrow,black] (l. right) |- (m. right);
%    \draw[arrow,black] (b. right) |- (m. left);
 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: intermediate]

Comment: I m still confused about having a text in a middle of an arrow. and yes I m pretty perplexed about it